# ajax Submit function doesn't return response but it updates database

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins

This is my first form using jquery to validate via client-side and I'm running into a problem with the .ajaxSubmit function (I also just used .ajax) and when clicking on submit button the database is updated but the ajax function doesn't return the results to the page. So, when I click on the submit button it looks like nothing is happening but when I look at the database the fields are updated with the data. Also, when I comment out the ajax function and just use the alert then when I click on the submit button the alert pops up. If someone can please assist me, as I've been working on this for a week now.

Here's the html and jQuery script:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
@import "./css/job.css";
-->
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($,W,D) {
    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function() {
            //form validation rules
            $("#job").validate({
                 rules: {
                        jobtype: {
                        required: true },
                        account: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 8 },
                        phone: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 7 },
                        comment: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5 },
                        available: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 3 }
                        },
                messages: {
                        jobtype: {
                        required: "Select a job type" },
                        account: {
                        required: "Enter account in correct format" },
                        phone: {
                        required: "Enter phone number" },
                        comment: {
                        required: "Enter WIP details" },
                        available: {
                        required: "Enter an available timeframe" }
                        },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
//                        alert("Submitting Job");
                        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                                        url: 'response.php',
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        data: {
                                        jobtype: $("#jobtype").val(),
                                        account: $("#account").val(),
                                        phone: $("#phone").val(),
                                        comment: $("#comment").val(),
                                        available: $("#available").val(),
                                        },
                                        dataType: 'json',
                                                cache: false,
                                        timeout: 7000,
                                        success: function(data) {
                                        $('form #schedTable').html(data.msg).fadeIn('fast');
                                }
                        });
                }
            });
        }
    }
    //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });
})(jQuery, window, document);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="jobForm">
<form id="job" name="job" action="response.php" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
<h1>Job Scheduling</h1>
<label>Type</label>
<select id="jobtype" name="jobtype">
  <option value="" selected>&lt;&lt; SELECT &gt;&gt;</option>
  <option value="service">Service</option>
  <option value="install">Install</option>
</select>
<label>Account</label>
<input type="text" id="account" name="account" maxlength="10" size="10">
<label>Phone</label>
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" maxlength="7" size="7">
<label>Comment</label>
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="2" cols="40" maxlength="40"></textarea>
<label>Available</label>
<input type="text" id="available" name="available" maxlength="20" size="20">
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
</form>
</div>

<div id="schedTable"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the response.php code:

```
<?php

$mydb connection info here

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Form</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>

<?php

// form inputs
$account = trim($_POST['account']);
$type = $_POST['type'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$comment = trim($_POST['comment']);
$available = trim($_POST['available']);

// Insert into mysql db
$ins = mysql_query(sprintf("INSERT INTO table (type,comment,available,phone,account) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')", $type,$comment,$available,$phone,$acct)) or die(mysql_error());

$sched = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY type asc"));

$return['msg'] = "
    <table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Account</th>
    <th>Comment</th>
    </tr>";

    while($rowu = mysql_fetch_array($sched)) {
    $return['msg'] .= "
        <tr>
        <td>{$type}</td>
        <td>{$acct}</td>
        <td>{$comment}</td>
        </tr>";
        }
        $return['msg'] .= "</table>";

       // header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8");
       // $return['msg'] = "Testing " .$account . "works";

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($return);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: I removed all of the html and the issue is the same while using chrome. When I use IE 8 and I click on the submit button it asks to open or save as a text file (repeats the same form data multiple times as well):

```
{"msg":"<table border='1'><tr>\n    <th>Type<\/th>\n    <th>Account<\/th>\n    <th>Comment<\/th>\n    <\/tr><tr>\n        <td>other<\/td>\n        <td>12345678<\/td>\n        <td>sssss<\/td>\n   <\/tr><tr>\n      <td>other<\/td>\n        <td>12345678<\/td>\n        <td>sssss<\/td>\n      <\/tr><tr>\n        <td>other<\/td>\n        <td>12345678<\/td>\n        <td>sssss<\/td>\n      <\/tr><\/table>"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response now works. I changed my code to the following and the results now show in my schedTable div without page refresh:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
     var data = $("#job").serialize();
     $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'response.php',
     data: data,
     cache: false,
     success: function(data) {  
          $('#job')[0].reset();
          $('#schedTable').html(data).fadeIn('fast');
     }
     });
}
```

However, now the results that are displayed are not entirely correct. Say, for instance, I submitted 3 jobs via the form, only the third job will display 3 times instead of all 3 jobs in the database displaying. Guess, I'm back to the drawing board with searching for this issue. Thanks for the advice Explosion Pills and Musa.

Update: Changing the while loop into a json array method fixed this issue. Everything is now working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Strip out all the html around the php logic. This is causing the problem, the response needs to be only json not html + json + html.

```
<?php

$mydb connection info here    

// form inputs
$account = trim($_POST['account']);
$type = $_POST['type'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$comment = trim($_POST['comment']);
$available = trim($_POST['available']);

// Insert into mysql db
$ins = mysql_query(sprintf("INSERT INTO table (type,comment,available,phone,account) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')", $type,$comment,$available,$phone,$acct)) or die(mysql_error());

$sched = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY type asc"));

$return['msg'] = "
    <table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Account</th>
    <th>Comment</th>
    </tr>";

    while($rowu = mysql_fetch_array($sched)) {
    $return['msg'] .= "
        <tr>
        <td>{$type}</td>
        <td>{$acct}</td>
        <td>{$comment}</td>
        </tr>";
        }
        $return['msg'] .= "</table>";

       // header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8");
       // $return['msg'] = "Testing " .$account . "works";

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: Thank you, I removed all html from the response.php file but the issue remains, see update above.

Answer (score 1):

Invalid JSON is being returned possibly due to the emission of a notice of undefined array index `msg` for `$return`, but more likely because of the emission of a lot of HTML.  Essentially this returns:

```
<some html>JSON<some html>
```

This is not valid JSON, so jQuery will not call the `success` callback.  Remove *all* of the HTML and emit *only* the JSON.

Comment: Thank you, I removed all html from the response.php file but the issue remains, see update above. I'm assuming the looping of the data is occurring because '$return' is undefined in my php file?